# I am getting ads for irrelevant jobs from careers 2.0 on right panel of Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, jobs, advertising

I think Stack Exchange should recommend us jobs based on what we are asking and what we are answering, and reputations earned on those things. Stack Exchange has enough data to determine depth and width of skill-set of its users.

There is not any other job portal which has exact technical profile of members as stack exchange has. But I think Stack Exchange is not using that data.

Answer (score 9):

Not to worry. We are working on a super secret project to do just that. To put it in trendy terms, we're hoping to "hyper target" ads in the future. Unfortunately the ETA is "this is way harder than we initially thought so some point in the future".

Comment: Not even 6-8 weeks? New territory for sure.

Comment: So [meta-tag:status-planned], or [meta-tag:status-review]?

Comment: @Juice while you guys are at it, job ads should also be based on what a user has said is a "liked" or "favorite" technology in his Careers 2.0 profile. I'm an ASP.NET/C# web developer moving into Ruby on Rails, which are all reflected in my Careers 2.0 profile, but I hardly answer any questions for those technologies on Stack Overflow (I'm mostly active in just the Git tag). I often see Java and Python ads, which are technologies that I have less or no interest in working with.

Comment: @cupcake Maybe you'll get your wish.......

Comment: @ShadowWizard Planeed, I updated the tags.

Comment: Yep, saw that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just to play devil advocate, what if the data collected is inaccurate or doesn't reflect what I am looking for, you might be showing me jobs I have zero interest in or hiding jobs I would be interested in.

- Maybe I am not active in tags on Stack Overflow in which I would be well qualified in working (possibly because the tag is a festering cesspool of low quality questions).
- What if I am looking to broaden my horizons.
- What if I am very active in tags in which I have zero interest in working in.  I might be well skilled in a specific language, but I don't enjoy actually developing in that language.

Ultimately unless the user has control over what they see, basing it solely on their interactions with the site could limit the potential job seekers who see the posts and make them less valuable to both the company looking to hire and the job seeker themselves.

Comment: This isn't really playing devils advocate. Looking at my tags I'll only ever be shown SQL  positions. SE doesn't know that I do a huge amount of data and product work or that I've fixed some bugs in a few Python packages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how their system works, but have you reviewed your profile, particularly the open source contributions?  If the system imported a bunch of open source stuff, and it isn't what you're primarily working on, that might skew things a bit towards those fields.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your adblock filter list

```
||cdn-careers.sstatic.net^$domain=stackoverflow.com
```

More info in my answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248217/233722)